# Permission denied: 'Msgbox'

Tags: vba

I am using VBA to create message boxes with Yes/No responses. For one in particular, the message box works fine but any message box I put after this one results in a Permission denied: 'Msgbox" error. My code looks something like this:

```
if msgbox ("Release this Assessment to the Team Leader?", vbyesno) = vbyes then
   msgbox "Released"
   else
   msgbox "Not released"
end if
```

So I get the first message box but for either selection (Yes or No) I get the error message. Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code....

Comment: I have tested your code and it works fine if I select "yes" or "No". I have also inserted a `MsgBox` after your code and that one works fine too.

Comment: Can you copy your code from your Visual Basic App and paste it here. I can see that you just typed your code in manually here.

Comment: Hi JP (@Jean_Pierre). Thanks for your response. It turns out the issue is not with the syntax. If I use the same code elsewhere, it works just fine. It is just in this one specific sub that I keep getting this error. I have no idea why. I will be moving the code to another logical location so the end result will be the same. Fingers crossed...

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
msgBox ("Release this Assessment to the Team Leader?", vbyesno)
select Case msgBox
    Case "Yes":
        msgBox "Released", vbokonly
    Case "No":
        msgBox "Not released, vbokonly
End Select
```